# New Badge Notification targets wrong post for Peer Pressure Badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

I [recently deleted an answer I provided](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56514/any-updates-on-stack-exchange-1-0-migration/56525#56525) to a question.  About 5 minutes later I received a notification that I was awarded the Peer Pressure badge for a [*completely different answer*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43334/what-has-just-happened/43335#43335).

Two issues:

1. The badge was awarded incorrectly - the text says:

   > Deleted **own** post with score of -3 or lower

   [I didn't delete the second answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43334/what-has-just-happened/43335#43335); a moderator did.
2. Even if (1) wasn't an issue, the badge should/shouldn't have been awarded for what I deleted today (depending on which path you take).

Comment: Make that three issues, Markdown overwrites a users' intentions when lists are separated by paragraphs but are the same list.

Comment: The users' intentions didn't match the users' actions.

Comment: As a side note (and I've already filed too many bug reports today, the search bar won't let you search for all open bugs in the system, it stops at `[bug] -[status-completed] -[status-bydesign] -[status-planned] -[status-norepro]` even though I still need -[status-declined] and -[status-review] removed from the search to find all the opened non-adjudicated bugs.

Comment: The search has a limit of 10 terms. That's 5 tags and 4 operators, which is what's killing you. Why not use [bug -status~](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+-status~)?

Comment: Good point. Let me try that.

Comment: It's working for me. That's the only reason I suggested it, complete with link. Unless you're referring to the term limit, which I'll admit was mostly out of conjecture from memory than on-hand proof.

Comment: I tried it by handwriting it and it didn't work. When I clicked on the link it worked.

Comment: @Grace Note what did you physically type to get that to work, I typed `[bug] -[status~]` and `[bug] -status~` and neither worked.

Comment: I typed `http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+-status~` in the URL to get it to work. I've long since stopped using the search bar for anything more complex than just NOT operators.

Comment: Reviewing queries .... please hold tight ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confirmed this bug and just pushed a patch, the only time people are notified are when they first get the badge, so sorry George you can not really confirm the fix.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks, Sam. Or Waffles.