# Badge notification targeted wrong post for Enlightened Badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

*Following on the heels of [other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56926/new-badge-notification-targets-wrong-post-for-peer-pressure-badge) [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57824/new-badge-notifications-targets-wrong-post-for-nice-answer) that have been linked to the wrong post in the notification...*

I recently got a badge notification that [I earned an Enlightened badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=52738) for [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569933/is-it-possible-to-define-more-than-one-function-per-file-in-matlab/3569946#3569946), when in fact the most recent post that [I earned a Nice Answer badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=52738) for was [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3470654/how-can-i-move-variables-into-and-out-of-a-structure-akin-to-load-and-save-in-mat/3470731#3470731) (which is the one I *really* should have gotten an Enlightened badge for).

It seems weird that the Nice Answer badge notification was correct, but the Enlightened badge notification was off. I don't know if this is a problem with the badge notification system in general, or something specific to my account like [waffles' answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57824/new-badge-notifications-targets-wrong-post-for-nice-answer/57831#57831) seems to suggest.

Can anyone take a look?

Comment: I don't see how it's wrong. You earned a Nice Answer badge for both answers, but only 1 Enlightened badge, and that's probably because the badge awarding script didn't run yet.

Comment: @Null: Note the times. I had just gotten the upvote which gave me a score of 10 and the Nice Answer badge, and the next Enlightened badge I got should have been for that same post, but it was for the older one I had long since had 12 upvotes on.

Comment: I don't know what the exact mechanics are, but all my "Enlightened" badges have been awarded after a "Nice Answer" badge was awarded for the same question, with one of them being awarded 5 days after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, this is a side effect of you getting the enlightened badge incorrectly for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667034/simple-physics-based-movement/667090#667090)

I'm looking at stripping off all the invalid enlightened badge reasons, then it will rebuild the missing reasons next time you get an enlightened badge.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't notice that incorrectly-awarded old question. Thanks!

Comment: @waffles: did you already perform those "invalid enlightened badge reasons" removals? Because I just lost 14 enlightened badges right now (user 6309 on SO)

Comment: Did you guys just invoke another resync?  I received a notification for earning the [Enlightened Badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=390278) which I've had for a while now.  I didn't get an additional badge but it's like it was refreshed or something.  The page shows it as just recently earned.  Perhaps related to @VonC's situation.

Comment: @VonC ... sorry, but yes, those badges were mostly given to people due to a system bug.

Comment: @waffles: no problem at all, I don't mind this "badge recalc" ;)

Comment: @Von ... also keep in mind this only affected enlightened badges. 4000 of them ... :)

Comment: @VonC: It looks like you have to wait for the database to finish granting our badges: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66268/someone-please-call-911-silver-badges-missing.