# What phase should migrating Stack Exchange 1.0 sites start in on Stack Exchange 2.0?

Tags: discussion, area-51, migration, stackexchange-2.0

Assuming the migrating sites are successful enough to migrate to SE 2.0, what Area51 phase should they start in?

Comment: did you have a specific site in mind? these are very much dependent on the site's characteristics

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Most interested in SharePoint Overflow as I'm admin there and we're likely to want to move to SE 2.0. But also wondering if there have been any general thoughts about this.

Comment: Related: [Does it make sense for Stack Exchange 1.0 sites that are active to go through Private Beta?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60042/does-it-make-sense-for-stack-exchange-1-0-sites-that-are-active-to-go-through-pri)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having founded a Stack Exchange 1.0 site, Basically Money, that was recently migrated into SE 2.0 as [money.stackexchange.com](http://money.stackexchange.com), here's my $0.02 on the subject:

**Stack Exchange 1.0 sites migrating into Stack Exchange 2.0 *should* still have a private beta, but the private beta MUST include all of the SE 1.0 site's registered users.** .. (in addition, of course, to the new users that committed to the area51 proposal.)

More in [my answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60042/does-it-make-sense-for-stack-exchange-1-0-sites-that-are-active-to-go-through-pri/60085#60085).

In a nutshell: There's value in a private beta, but don't slam the door on the SE 1.0 user base.

Answer (score 2):

Well, they are public already, aren't they? I would say that, if they meet the necessary criteria to survive like number of users and size of traffic, this should be a rather seamless thing for the users. Therefore I would say they start as public site right away, just with a new, slightly different feature set.

All sites that do not meet the necessary criteria can easily undergo the full Area51 proposal process and save themselves by this time generating more interest. In this case, the mods of the old site should have the possibility to clean up the question body which then should be migrated to seed the beta phase.

Answer (score 1):

At this point I don't have a definite opinion on what phase the sites should start on, but I thought it might be useful to post some information on how it is working at the moment. There has already been one migration and there a few proposals that could be migrations.

The site that made the move was called Basically Money (now the [Personal Finance and Money beta](https://money.stackexchange.com/)) and it went through the [same stages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721/personal-finance-and-money) as the other proposed sites. There is also a current [Libraries proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12432/libraries) in the commitment phase that is a proposed migration from [Unshelved Answers](http://unshelvedanswers.com)).

Of the proposals in the definition phase I am aware of at least two that appear to be based on existing 1.0 sites:

- [Skeptic Exchange](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12612/skeptic-exchange) (see [Skeptic Exchange](http://www.skepticexchange.org/))
- [EVE Online](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3371/eve-online) (see [Skill Training Complete](http://skilltrainingcomplete.com/))

There may be some others, but these are the only ones that I have seen so far.