# What differences will "upgraded" Stack Exchange 1.0 sites have compared to other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Currently the [OnStartups answers site](http://answers.onstartups.com/):

- Doesn't have a meta.
- Uses a third-party domain.
- Has the existing owners as diamond mods.

Will these differences also be in the gold site? What other differences will this and other "upgraded" Stack Exchange 1.0 sites have from sites like Web Applications?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We're working one-on-one with the owners of sites when we import them, so there's no general rule.  However, we're trying to keep the differences minimal.

- [answers.onstartups](http://answers.onstartups.com) will soon have a meta.  We ran into some issues with DNS (since it's not our domain) that should be resolved tomorrow
- A 3rd-party domain will only happen in rare circumstances, and where it makes sense with the intended community.  In this case, it's a mutually beneficial relationship since OnStartups.com is an excellent blog on entrepeneurship
- Moderators will still be chosen by the community.  There may be some "extra" mods like Stack Overflow, Inc. staff and those we have special relationships with, like Dharmesh and Jason in this case, but we'll try to keep a light touch and let the community govern itself.

Another difference that you didn't mention is that imported sites from now on will skip private beta, so existing users aren't locked out for a week.  The main purpose of private beta is to fill initial content and set the basic tone, and in a site that's imported that is already done.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention the private beta because that won't affect the final site.

Comment: +1 for "imported sites from now on will skip private beta."  Great decision.