# Why is it that MathOverflow.net is not a part of SE 2.0?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0

I find it weird that [mathoverflow.net](http://mathoverflow.net) is not a part of SE 2.0 sites. Any reason why?

The software behind [mathoverflow.net](http://mathoverflow.net) is a bit old, and it can use some updating. Don't you agree?

**Edit: One of the thread I found on MO meta is [this](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/454/linking-in-with-stackoverlow-al/), which leads me to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56514/any-updates-on-stack-exchange-1-0-migration). Now a few months have passed, what is the latest development?**

Comment: Close as "no longer relevant"??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It took a while to get to this point, but [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/) is now a part of the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: So what is the difference between MathOverflow and math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @corsiKa MathOverflow is for research-level mathematics, and Math SE is for all levels. (Within the scope defined in their respective help centers.) In the simplest terms, it's a similar split as what we have with [cstheory.SE] and [cs.SE].

Comment: @corsiKa http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/271/how-is-this-site-different-to-math-stackexchange

Answer (score 7):

MathOverflow is currently still on the Stack Exchange 1.0 system. Unlike many of the other old SE 1.0 sites, it had developed a stable community. Since it was working fine (I think Stack Exchange had agreed to keep hosting MO as a 1.0 site for as long as they wanted.), and there were concerns that closer integration with SE would flood it with non-mathematician questions and voters, they held off migrating.

Eventually, [a community consensus emerged](https://web.archive.org/web/20130327140640/https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1082/1/migrate-to-se-20/) to migrate to the SE 2.0 network. The main MathOverflow administrator, Anton Geraschenko, came out in favor of migration. However, for some years it was held up in negotiations. The negotiations were largely over how to add it to the main SE network without compromising MO's distinctive research-oriented community, and allowing MO to leave SE in case it doesn't work out.

However, as of 2013-02-06, it appears that migration to the SE 2.0 network is very close. I believe they have already tested a trial migration site. Yesterday, [Anton Geraschenko posted on MO's then-meta forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20130519134912/https://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1416/5/mathoverflow-20/):

> Yes. The agreement with Stack Exchange has been settled (and vetted by lawyers). We're in the process of getting some grant money to make a MathOverflow legal entity, and this is holding up the agreement with Stack Exchange (the agreement is between SE and the MO entity). Everything is taking longer than expected, but things really are moving forward behind the scenes--I promise!

Comment: In the [latest podcast](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/02/podcast-42-2/?cb=1) Joel also briefly mentions the site and its conversion to SE 2.0, though nothing in-depth.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you go to https://meta.mathoverflow.net and [search for the word "migration".](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/search?q=migration)

Comment: Note that you have to select search in 'comments' to get any results back (default is topics).

Comment: One of the thread I found is [this](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/454/linking-in-with-stackoverlow-al/), which leads me to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56514/any-updates-on-stack-exchange-1-0-migration). Now a few months have passed, what is the latest development?

Comment: @Ngu: if you are really interested in the MO side of things, you should ask this question at meta.MO.